# Multiple Knapsack with Varying Values

Tags: python, or-tools, assignment-problem, knapsack

I wish to assign customers to their nearest distribution hubs. These hubs have maximum capacities however, and if these are breached I would like to assign customers to the next most appropriate hub.

Currently I am trying to use a multiple knapsack problem in or-tools (happy to use other) to code a python warehouse optimisation.

In this scenario I am treating the drivetime as my value (although I actually seek to minimise it so am using the inverse square) and the capacity as a weight.

The problem is that the value (drivetime) will vary by warehouse and therefore changes.

Is there any solutions to solve this?

I think knapsack is the correct solution, but if there is something else I should try please feel free to correct me - for example assignment feels potentially more appropriate.

Am trying to do in Python as well.

Comment: Could you give some details about your problem (how is the drivetime defined, what are your variables, why it is multiple knapsack problem, etc.) ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Would you like to assign customers to warehouses at minimum cost ?

Comment: Sounds like the *capacitated facility location* problem.

Comment: @RobPratt If the warehouses are already at fixed locations, is it really a facility location problem?

Comment: @prubin I guess not.  I agree that GAP is a better fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a [generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem). You can solve it with a MIP solver and any suitable Python modeling package/interface. I'm not a Python user, but [Pyomo](https://www.pyomo.org/about) and [PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/) seem to be popular choices.

Comment: Or-tools also includes a MILP modeler https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/mip_example